# Sencha Architect stuck on Loading <MyProject>.. forever Architect 4.3.0

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

I installed the new version created a new project and when I tried to reopen it it always waits

Comment: I removed all folders regarding SA installation and all sencha cmd
I removed java from my mac

I re-install JDK 1.8
I re-install SA 4.2.9 - 443

After that I created a new project and now all my issues are go away.

I'm convince myself that all issues has been happen by a wrong java version.
My previously java version was 17.

I will wait for news on new SA version

After two trouble days now I go to bed cloudless
Thk for your support please close this ticket

Answer (score 0):

after installing or updating the architect you must download and install the CMD as well.